# 20.04 just uninstalled my Chromium Version 83.0.4103.97 what did I do to allow that

Tags: 20.04, chromium, gnome-shell-extension

How did I allow my Chromium Version 83.0.4103.97  to be uninstalled or did I?  Also with 20.04 why did I just see for the first time the message about 75 and above Chromium only available to Ubuntu Users through the snap package?

How do I force Ubuntu to not make the decision for me?  I feel like I'm back in Windows territory for a moment?  Paranoid and not liking there decisions is why I left them.

How do I force my version that likes gnome extensions working and not being removed?

I'm just trying to understand what I can't seem to understand thru  online research.

Thank you,

mrbill

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't uninstall softwares on it's own. Many softwares are not available in latest version in software centre to ensure stability of the system, but even older versions runs just fine.

Comment: Did you upgrade distro to 20.04?

Comment: Was Chromium itself uninstalled or was it updated to higher number?  Most Linux update most of the software on the system when new updates are available, if you have updates enable.  PPAs are disabled during upgrades of versions(19.10 to 20.04)  There is a way to lock a specific version of a software from being updated, but need google or someone else to find.